# Catch text within a rounded bracket with quotes

Tags: c#, .net

I am still new to using Regex.
I'm on a project in C # and need to get a value that is within a bracket.
The Code is `<$ Execute ['WebF'] $>` I want to return the value WebF.
Agredeço much for your help.

@EDIT

My Code is `<$Execute['WebF']$>` without space

@EDIT

Thanks to doNet :).
Code that returned the value `\<\$+Execute+\['(?<DATA>\w+)'\]+\$\>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\<\$\s+Execute\s+\['(?<DATA>\w+)'\]\s+\$\>
```

Run it with ExplicitCapture and IgnoreCase flags.

Comment: I tried using the following code and the result was error            Match m = new Regex(@"\<\$\s+Execute\s+\['(?<DATA>\w+)'\]\s+\$\>", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match("<$Execute['WebF']$>");
            if (m.Success)
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error");

Comment: Thanks :) Code returns WebF : \<\$+Execute+\['(?<DATA>\w+)'\]+\$\>

Comment: A thanks is better expressed by marking it as answer, not only to help responder, but also a future reader.

Comment: New Error =/ Match m = new Regex(@"\<\$+Execute+\['(?<DATA>\w+)'\]+\$\>").Match("<$Execute['Web.Fcs']$>"); return success = false, without "." return success = true

Comment: Man. SO is not for asking others to do your homework. Go, read some good stuff on Regular Expressions language and you'll figure out how to modify the above expression.